# When a field is programatically set to Read Only the heading is still Blue indicating that is is editable

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I’m starting to get into the build phase of the app now.
One of the requirements that we have is that we need to put a JobPlan on a follow up workorder.
I have this done (setting all the classifications etc.).

The problem that I have is when this is sent to Maximo it updates the Workorder description based on the JobPlan and specifications … which is fine.
What I want to do in Anywhere is have the Description set to read only when there is a JobPlan to prevent it being overwritten.
(the WO description is set from the JobPlan lookup overwrites it with the JP description).
This all works fine.

The last piece of the puzzle is that whilst the Description is read only the heading is still blue indicating it is writable (compare Description to Status) in the screen shot below.
This is likely to cause confusion for our users.

Is there any way to dynamically toggle heading style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you paste in the line where you are programmatically setting the field to read only? This should be supported and I think we fixed the label to inherit the read only metadata correctly in 752 fix pack 1.

Comment: var jpnum = wo.get('jpnum');

var readOnly = !(jpnum == null || jpnum == '');
wo.getRuntimeFieldMetadata('description').set('readonly', readOnly);

Comment: Looks like I was having problems getting my environment upgraded to 7521 from the 7521preview.

I have upgraded now and the 7521 official fix pack does indeed fix this.